# ASP.NET MVC Custom Validation (Conditionally required)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I'm having an issue with custom validation in ASP.NET MVC. I want to achieve conditional required validation for ServerName property below. The condition is if ServerSpecific property is true then ServerName should be a required field. I have used Validate method to do it but for some reason that particular code Vlaidate methof never hits in any condition. Is there anything missing here?

```
public class PlatformConfigurationEditModel : IValidatableObject
{
    #region Constructor
    public PlatformConfigurationEditModel()
    {
        SettingEnabled = true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ServerSpecific == true && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerName)) 
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Please provide Server Name!.");
        }
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int PlatformProfileId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int EnvironmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Setting Name")]
    [JqGridColumnEditable(true, EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.Text)]
    public string SettingName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JqGridColumnEditable(true, EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Setting Value")]
    public string SettingValue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Setting Enabled")]
    [JqGridColumnSearchable(false)]
    [JqGridColumnEditable(true, EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.CheckBox)]
    public bool SettingEnabled { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Server Specific")]
    [JqGridColumnSearchable(false)]
    [JqGridColumnEditable(true, EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.CheckBox)]
    public Nullable<bool> ServerSpecific { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Server Name")]
    [JqGridColumnEditable(true, "GetServers", "Profile", EditType = 
                                                  JqGridColumnEditTypes.Select)]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Nullable<int> ServerId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProfileVersionId { get; set; }

  }
```

}

Controller Action Method

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(
        [ModelBinder(typeof(PlatformConfigurationEditModelBinder))]
        PlatformConfigurationEditModel platformconfiguration)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            #region web binding value adjustments

            if (platformconfiguration.SettingName.ToLower() == "webbinding")
            {
                platformconfiguration.SettingValue = ModifyWebBinding  
                (platformconfiguration.SettingValue);
            }

            #endregion

            var updatedEntity = From<PlatformConfigurationEditModel>.To<PlatformConfiguration>
                                 (platformconfiguration);
            ////
            //// update server id
            ////

            if (updatedEntity.ServerSpecific.HasValue && updatedEntity.ServerSpecific.Value)
            {
                updatedEntity.ServerId = Convert.ToInt32(platformconfiguration.ServerName);
            }

            _context.PlatformConfigurations.Add(updatedEntity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Add");

    }
```

Model Binder-

```
 public class PlatformConfigurationEditModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        int environmentId;
        int profileId;
        int id = 0;
        int pfvid;

        string paramdata = request.Params["Id"];

        if (!paramdata.Equals("_empty"))
        {
            int[] data = request.Params["id"].Split('-').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray
            ();
            id = data[0];
            profileId = data[1];
            environmentId = data[2];
            pfvid = data[3];
        }
        else
        {
            id = 0;
            int[] extdt = request.Params["ExtData"].Split('-').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32
            (n)).ToArray();
            profileId = extdt[0];
            environmentId = extdt[1];
            pfvid = extdt[2];
        }

        string settingEnabled = request.Params["SettingEnabled"];
        string serverSpecific = request.Params["ServerSpecific"];

        string settingName = request.Params["SettingName"];
        string settingValue = request.Params["SettingValue"];
        string serverName = request.Params["ServerName"];


        return new PlatformConfigurationEditModel
            {
                Id = id,
                EnvironmentId = environmentId,
                PlatformProfileId = profileId,
                ServerSpecific = serverSpecific.ToLower() == "on" || serverSpecific.ToLower() 
                == "true",
                SettingEnabled = settingEnabled.ToLower() == "on" || settingEnabled.ToLower() 
                == "true",
                ServerName = serverName,
                SettingName = settingName,
                SettingValue = settingValue,
                ProfileVersionId = pfvid
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `ServerSpecific == true`?

Comment: Have you tried FluentValidation? http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Comment: You need to show us your controller method

Comment: @Murali - Thanks for the reply . When i had a break point in Validate method that never gets hit and yes that is true.

Comment: You're using a custom model binder.. you are responsible for calling Validate

Comment: Could you show in code where i should make change @MystereMan

Comment: You need to show your custom model binder.

Comment: @MystereMan - Hi updated ModelBinder code. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add your validations to the model binder?

Answer (score 0):

I would make your custom model binder inherit from DefaulModelBinder instead of IModelBinder. Then call the base implementation at the end, and you will then get your Validation support.

You might even consider using Jimmy Bogard's "Smart Binder"

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/03/18/a-better-model-binder/

This allows you to create an array of model binders that still all call the base implementation when they're done.

Keep in mind that Validate only gets called after all other validations have succeeded.  That means, if you have client-side validation, those validations will fail first.  And the user will have to fix those before the IValidatableObject.Validate will get called.

Another good resource are these two articles:

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx